# htaccess - redirect entire site wild card not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

From my understanding this should redirect any url to the new domain version

For instance

http://www.olddomain.com redirects to http://www.newdomain.com just fine

but

anything else like http://www.olddomain/1/2/3 does not redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/1/2/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This will redirect all wildcard `http://www.olddomain.com/1/2/3` URIs to `http://www.newdomain.com/1/2/3`